# Relative positions of four points in plane

Tags: algorithm, graph, geometry

There are two different relative positions for four points in the plane:

[image: Points]

In position 1, the four points can form a convex quadrilateral, (which is their [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull#Convex_hull_of_a_finite_point_set)), and in position 2, they can't (and their convex hull is a triangle). My question is: How can I write an algorithm to find out if the points are in position 1 or 2? (I know the coordinates of all four points).

Comment: First, write an algorithm that finds the convex hull of the points. Then, compare the number of vertices in the convex hull with the number of points on the plane. If they're equal, it's position 1. If they aren't, it's position 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any triple of points P, Q and R in the plane, (not collinear), you can determine whether the angle P-Q-R makes a counterclockwise or a clockwise turn by looking at the sign of the quantity:

```
(P[0] - R[0]) * (Q[1] - R[1]) - (P[1] - R[1]) * (Q[0] - R[0])
```

where `P[0]` and `P[1]` refer to the x- and y-coordinates of P respectively, and similarly for Q and R.

Now call your four points P1, P2, P3 and P4, and compute these signs for each of the four triples (P1, P2, P3), (P1, P2, P4), (P1, P3, P4) and (P2, P3, P4) (be careful here: the order of the points (P, Q, R) in the expression above matters).  If all signs are equal, or there are two positive and two negative signs, the convex hull is a quadrilateral.  If there are three positive and one negative sign (or the other way around), the convex hull of your four points is a triangle.  Or put more simply, if your signs are represented as +1 and -1, multiply the four signs together.  If the product is +1, you're in the quadrilateral case; if -1, you're in the triangular case.

The above assumes that no three of the four points are collinear; I leave it to you to enumerate the degenerate cases.

And since this is StackOverflow, here's some code (in Python).  First the definition of `ccw` (making use of a `sign` helper function).

```
def sign(x):
    """ Return the sign of a finite number x. """
    if x > 0:
        return 1
    elif x < 0:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

def ccw(P, Q, R):
    """ Return 1 if P-Q-R is a counterclockwise turn, -1 for clockwise,
        and 0 if the points are collinear (or not all distinct). """
    disc = (P[0] - R[0]) * (Q[1] - R[1]) - (P[1] - R[1]) * (Q[0] - R[0])
    return sign(disc)
```

Then the classification of a quadruple of points.

```
def classify_points(P, Q, R, S):
    """ Return 1 if the convex hull of P, Q, R and S is a quadrilateral,
        -1 if a triangle, and 0 if any three of P, Q, R and S are
        collinear (or if not all points are distinct). """
    return ccw(P, Q, R) * ccw(P, Q, S) * ccw(P, R, S) * ccw(Q, R, S)
```

A simple test: a square should be classified with the result `1`.

```
>>> # Test case 1: quadrilateral convex hull
>>> P = 0, 0
>>> Q = 0, 1
>>> R = 1, 0
>>> S = 1, 1
>>> classify_points(P, Q, R, S)
1
```

And a triangle with result `-1`.

```
>>> # Test case 2: triangle.
>>> P = 0, 0
>>> Q = 0, 3
>>> R = 3, 0
>>> S = 1, 1
>>> classify_points(P, Q, R, S)
-1
```

And here's a degenerate case (P, Q and S are collinear):

```
>>> P = 1, 1
>>> Q = 2, 2
>>> R = 5, 7
>>> S = 4, 4
>>> classify_points(P, Q, R, S)
0
```

Note that if you're using inexact floating-point arithmetic, numerical errors could result in a near-degenerate case being classified as degenerate, or vice versa.

To justify the above: it's easy to check that swapping any two inputs in the `ccw` definition reverses the sign of the result, and that swapping any two inputs in the `classify_points` definition leaves the sign of the product unaltered.  So we can reorder the points arbitrarily with affecting the `classify_points` result.

Now suppose that P1, P2, P3 and P4 have a quadrilateral convex hull.  Then by the above observation, we can reorder the points to assume that P1, P2, P3 and P4 go around the boundary of that quadrilateral in counterclockwise order.  Then each of the `ccw` expressions is `1`, and so the result of `classify_points` is `1`.  Similarly, if P1, P2, P3 and P4 have triangular convex hull, we can rearrange so that P1, P2 and P3 go counterclockwise around the triangle boundary and P4 is within the triangle, and in that case the `ccw` signs are `1`, `1`, `-1` and `1`.